# address sanitizer not detecting memory leaks in a simple c++ program

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I am a bit confused as why address sanitizer is not detecting an obvious memory leak and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int * p = new int;
    delete p; 

    // Memory leak
    double *pter = new double(32.54);

    // no delete

}
```

I compile using `g++ -g -fsanitize=address -o main main.cpp` 
and run it using `./main` and nothing happens. I feel like I am missing something very trivial and I am not sure what though.

Comment: address sanitizer is mostly a memory error detector, not a leak detector

Comment: @user7860670 damn. I wanted to use it as a substitute for valgrind to detect leaks. Thanks

Comment: You can try https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html instead.

Comment: @Surt Oh wow. Bad googling on my part. Thanks